# How can I get every value name from a Model List

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project who need to list and store some model's content and add it in list.

Here is my model :

```
public class ProductPage
    {

           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string Reference { get; set; }
           public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my code :

```
public List<TechnicalAttributes> GetAttributeFromProduct(ProductPage product)
        {
            List<TechnicalAttributes> attributeList = new List<TechnicalAttributes>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in product.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    string value = (string)pi.GetValue(product);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        if (!Helper.IsNumeric(value))
                        {
                            attributeList.Add(new TechnicalAttributes() { Name = GetVariableName(() => value), Value = value });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return attributeList;
        }
```

My code allow me to get this :

```
type = "value" - attribute = "myName"
type = "value" - attribute = "myReference"
type = "value" - attribute = "myColor"
```

but I want to have something like this :

```
type = "Name" - attribute = "myName"
type = "Reference" - attribute = "myReference"
type = "Color" - attribute = "myColor"
```

I need to use a foreach because I have way more parameters in my model !
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: I don't know what `GetVariableName` is supposed to do,
 but what you need is: [MemberInfo.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) (`PropertyInfo` inherits from `MemberInfo`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use `pi.Name` to get the name of the property.

This property is part of [`System.Reflection.MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) and is available in `PropertyInfo` as well. It will give you the name of the property.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved,

You can have the parameters name with the property Info.

```
pi.Name;
```